# How can I create a Hamburger menu using a tab button from bottom tabs in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to create a hamburger menu that will pop up on top of the current screen when you press the more button. [Image of desired outcome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h0yH.png)
Sort of something like this.

`<Tab.Screen name="More" component={HamburgerMenuFunc} options={{ tabBarLabel: 'More', tabBarIcon:  ({ focused }) => ( <Entypo name='menu' size={34} color={focused ? "#32ACE0":"white"} /> )}} />`

I used the code above to reference a function in the component property to try and see if an alert would pop up while on the same screen however it will take me to seperate blank page instead.

Answer (score 0):

Implement custom `tabBar` and override default behaviour (i.e. navigation) to show a menu.

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Toys" component={ToysScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="More" />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

See [tabbar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar) for details.